# MySQLi plugin not loaded

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently upgraded to MySQL 5.7.9 from having previously used 5.5 (by removing the old mysql and installing the new one). Now when I run a PHP script (which used to work), I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1524): Plugin
>   '*8CC466EE1F3C4B48CF50D1E337EE808AC922A16E' is not loaded in...

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling php5-mysql by using `sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql && sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`?

Comment: Yes I did... now PHP Version 5.5.30-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1

Comment: Does the error show in the mysql error logs, or is this warning php specifically?

Comment: i would suggest removing both MySQL and and PHP. After that reinstall PHP and then MySQL (in that order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, in my case, the user record in the `mysql.users` table didn't have the full grant privileges and was causing this error.

Comment: I gave the user full grant privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation. I removed that user and added it back with same privileges and the error was gone and all works now.